# How to delete particular nested json attribute

Tags: javascript, json

I want to delete __metadata where ever it appears .How to do that I searched this question but didn't get exact solution. hope you will help me out .

```
{
  "__metadata":{
     "uri":"asd",
     "type":"DP_CART_SRV.DPCARTHeader"
  },
  "Dealer":{
     "__metadata":{
        "uri":"asd"
     },
     "CustomerNo":"",
     "Name1":"",
     "Name2":""
  },
  "Retailer":{
     "__metadata":{
        "uri":"asd"
     },
     "CustomerNo":"",
     "Name1":"",
     "Name2":""
  },
  "Cart":"0000000081",
  "Type":"SH",
  "CreatedOn":"/Date(1399420800000)/",
  "ChangedOn":null,
  "OrderId":"",
  "OrderType":"",
  "ReqDeliveryDate":"2014/05/31",
  "OrderValue":"11.00",
  "DocCurrency":"EUR",
  "NetValue":"11.00",
  "Freight":"0.00",
  "Discount":"0.00",
  "Tax":"0.00",
  "Remarks":"Remarks",
  "Items":{
     "results":[
        {
           "__metadata":{
              "uri":"asd"
           },
           "Cart":"0000000081",
           "ItemNo":"000010",
           "ProductID":"FAN_FG1",
           "ItemDesc":"Finshed product FAN",
           "Quantity":"1.000",
           "Uom":"KAR",
           "Price":"11.00",
           "Currency":"EUR",
           "Available":"",
           "DeleteStatus":""
        },
        {
           "__metadata":{
              "uri":"",
              "type":""
           },
           "DeleteStatus":"",
           "Available":"",
           "Currency":"",
           "Price":"",
           "Uom":"",
           "Quantity":"",
           "ItemDesc":"",
           "ProductID":"",
           "ItemNo":"",
           "Cart":""
        }
     ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a fun one. Not very obvious way how you can do it:

```
var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj, function(key, value) {
    return key !== '__metadata' ? value : undefined;
}));
```

It makes use of the `replacer` function [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method accepts:

> replacer
>   If a function, transforms values and properties encountered while stringifying; if an array, specifies the set of properties included in objects in the final string.
>   A detailed description of the replacer function is provided in the javaScript guide article Using native JSON.

**However be aware that this is not intended JSON.stringify and JSON.parse usage.** Also of course the `result` will no longer be the original object, but a *new* object.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7Gj47/

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know what you mean by "nested json attribute". The OP appears to be an object literal, which is the syntax used for JSON, however JSON is a string.

Anyhow, supposing you have JSON, it can be turned into an object using JSON.parse. You can then iterate over the object and remove any property with a certain name, and recursively remove properties from "nested" objects using a function like:

```
function removeProp(obj, propName) {

  for (var p in obj) {

    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {

      if (p == propName) {
        delete obj[p];

      } else if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
        removeProp(obj[p], propName);
      }
    }
  }
  return obj;
}
```

So if you have JSON (i.e. text representing an object), you can remove all instances of a particular property using something like:

```
var jsonText = '{ ... }';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
removeProp(obj, '__metadata');
jsonText = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

The function could take a third parameter that specifies if it should check nested objects or not.